# Regex - Greek Characters in URL

Tags: php, regex, url, routes, url-encoding

I have a custom router that uses regex.

The problem is that I cannot parse Greek characters.

---

Here are some lines from `index.php`:

```
$router->get('/theatre/plays', 'TheatreController', 'showPlays');
$router->get('/theatre/interviews', 'TheatreController', 'showInterviews');
$router->get('/theatre/[-\w\d\!\.]+', 'TheatreController', 'single_post');
```

---

Here are some lines from `Router.php`:

```
$found = 0;
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); //get the url

////// Bla Bla Bla /////////

if ( $found = preg_match("#^$value$#", $path) )
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

---

Now, when I try a url like `http://kourtis.app/theatre/α` (notice the last character is a Greek 'alpha') then it is somehow interpreted to `http://kourtis.app/theatre/%CE%B1`

I can see this when I `var_dump($path)` or when I copy-paste the url.

---

I guess it has something to do with encoding but everything (I can think of) is in utf-8 format.

Any ideas?

### --------------------------------

UPDATE: After the suggestions in the comments, the following works for ***only with some*** Greek characters:
`/theatre/[α-ωΑ-Ω-\w\d\!\.]+`
and use `urldecode` to decode the percent-encoding of the `$path` variable.

Some characters that produce an error are: `κ` `π` `ρ` `χ`.

The question now is ... why??
(BTW, this works for many chars `/theatre/.+`)

Comment: *I guess it has something to do with encoding* - indeed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Comment: try adding `u` as a modifier to your regex: for example  `/[-\w\d\!\.]+/u`

Comment: thank you all. The issue is resolved when I use `urldecode` to decode the `$path` variable and then add in my `index.php` this: `'/theatre/[α-ωΑ-Ω-\w\d\!\.]+'`. The /u modifier didn't work. It would be nice if somebody wrote an actual answer to the question explaining this stuff (urldecode, /u, percent encoding, etc.)

Comment: Why not use `$router->get('/theatre/[^/]+', 'TheatreController', 'single_post');`? Note you do not have to use `\d` if you used `\w`. Also, you did not match diacritics - add `\p{M}` to the regex: `'/theatre/[-\w\p{M}!.]+'`. Also `if ( $found = preg_match("#^$value$#u", $path) )` must be used to allow UTF texts and pattern  handling.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Thank you for your comment. Your anwser seems to be working. I tested with this: `http://kourtis.app/theatre/εδακζχ`. Also, it would be even better if you created an answer explaining about your logic. What is #u? Why `[^/]` is better than `[-\w\p{M}!.]+`? Finally maybe your regex should be `[-\w\p{M}!\.]+` instead of `[-\w\p{M}!.]+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$router->get('/theatre/[^/]+', 'TheatreController', 'single_post');
```

as `[^/]+` will match *one or more characters other than `/`* since `[^...]` is a *negated character class* that matches any char but the one(s)  defined in the class.

Note you do not have to use `\d` if you used `\w` (`\w` already matches digits).

Also, you did not match diacritics with your regex. If you need to match diacritics, add `\p{M}` to the regex: `'/theatre/[-\w\p{M}!.]+'`.

Note that to allow `\w` to match Unicode letters/digits, you need to pass `/u` modifier to the regex: `$found = preg_match("#^$value$#u", $path)`. This will both treat input strings as Unicode strings, and make shorthand patterns like `\w` Unicode aware.

Another thing: you need not escape `.` inside a character class.

**Pattern details**:

- `#...#` - regex delimiters
- `^` - start of string
- `$value` - the `$value` variable contents (since double quoted strings in PHP allow interpolation)
- `$` - end of string
- `#u`  - the modifier enabling *PCRE_UTF* and *PCRE_UCP* options. See more info about them here

Comment: Great answer! One question: if the modifier is `/u`, why do we pass only `u` in the `preg_match`? In general, can you explain what exactly the symbols in `#^$value$#u` mean?

Comment: I updated the answer with the description of the regex.